# Ruby on Rails - Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

So I do not reinvent the wheel, what is the best way to setup a registration, login, logout and password reset framework for Ruby on Rails?  Ideally, there must be a gem (library, package, etc) that handles this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authlogic, see [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic), and restful_authenticaction, see [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication).

Those two should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

[Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) and [restful-authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master) are two of the big ones. Also, have a look at the [search results on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+authentication).

Comment: Does restful-auth have password resets?

Answer (score 2):

[RESTful authentication plugin](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master):

> "Restful Authentication has been the standard authentication plugin/gem for Ruby on Rails for a long time. It works nicely and has hooks for role authorization."

Also, [Authlogic plugin](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) which is a common authentication plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Thoughtbot's clearance](http://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/tree/master). Install the gem and its up and running - it is a Rails engine.

If all you need is what you originally asked, this is easier by far. If you intend to add OpenID or more complex scenarios, Authlogic is the way to go.